# WP update_option() from $_POST array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, string

At first glance, this would be a simple question because I would normally do this with no problem.  However, in this case, the $_POST array will have an unknown number of keys due to the fact that the form uses repeating blocks.  Therefore, what I am trying to do is get all of the keys and values from the POST REQUEST and format them within an array in order to update WordPress user options with update_option().

The following will obtain the keys and values from the submitted form..

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
$newitem = array($key => $val);
// format the array items
}
```

But then I am trying to get these keys and values to automatically populate an array in order to look like this example...

```
$new_options = array(
'fav_number' => $_REQUEST['fav_number'],
'fav_color' => $_REQUEST['fav_color'],
);
update_option($user->user_nicename . '_plugin_options', $new_options);
```

I have tried to use foreach in order to format the incoming keys and values in order to populate the array.  I even tried this extremely ugly approach as kinda of a 'hack' but even this does nothing to help...

```
$output = print_r($_POST, true);
$output = str_replace(array("[action] => submit", "\"", "    ", "[", "]", "> "), array("", "", "", "'", "'", "> '"), $output);
$output = str_replace(array("\n'", ""), array("', \n'", ""), $output);
$output = str_replace(array("Array\n(\n', ", "\n)"), array("", "'"), $output);
```

When the form is submitted, all I get is either blank results, "a" in every result, or errors.

Can anyone out there tell me if there is a way to do this properly and effectively?

Comment: I just receive the general WordPress error that something went wrong with my site.  Clicking the 'learn more..' link provided very little help.  Got it resolved through another user here but thought you deserved a response, at the very least.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this way when don't know about keys

```
unset($_POST['action']);
$new_items = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$val) {
    // format the array items
    $new_items[$key] = $val;
}
update_option($user->user_nicename . '_plugin_options', 
$new_items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array in the `foreach`:

```
$new_options = [];
foreach (['fav_number', 'fav_color'] as $key) {
    $val = $_POST[$key];
    // format the array items
    $new_options[$key] = $val;
}
update_option($user->user_nicename . '_plugin_options', $new_options);
```